# How do you turn off "snap to grid" in OneNote 2016?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I want to exactly position some items in OneNote but things keep snapping to an invisible grid.

How do I turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to turn off the Snap to Grid feature this way:

[image]

1. Click the Draw tab
2. Click the down arrow in the Shapes section

[image]

3. Deselect the Snap to Grid item

Answer (score 2):

Hold alt while moving the text

Comment: This works in "OneNote for Windows 10", at least in Version ~ 16001